# Best way to bind a dropdown at client side

Tags: jquery, asp.net

what is the best way to bind a dropdown at client side using JQuery

Comment: Do u want to bind data from server at client (AJAX)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are asking how to bind an event to a `select` element...

```
$('select').change(function() {
   ...
});
```

Comment: No i am asking binding a list to a dropdown as we do it at server side using datasource property